# Symfony2: form submission returns form

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am trying edit an entity in form. If the name of the entity is 'My Entity' form looks different from regular, the name field is disabled and there is no 'Delete' button. When I submit regular entity edit form, it works fine. But when I try to submit changes to 'My Entity', it returns form

This is my form twig for edit:

```
<div class="collection-create">
<h3>Edit a collection</h3>
<form id="edit-form" method='POST' action="{{ path('edit_entity', {'id': entity.id}) }}">
    {% if entity.name == 'My entity' %}
        {{ form_row(form.name, { 'attr':{'disabled':'disabled'} }) }}
    {% else %}
        {{ form_row(form.name) }}
    {% endif %}

    {% if entity.name != 'Saved for later' %}
        <a class="button">Delete</a>
    {% endif %}

    <button type="submit"onclick="editCollection('{{ entity.id }}')">Save</button>
</form>
```

Controller

```
 /**
 * @Route("/edit/{id}", name="edit_entity")
 * @Template()
 */
public function editAction(Entity $entity, Request $request)
{

    $form = $this->createForm(new EntityType(), $entity, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('edit_entity',['id' => $entity->getId()]),
        'method' => 'POST'));

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid() && $form->isSubmitted()) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->render('@Entity/Entity/submit.html.twig', array(
            'entity' => $entity));
    }
    return array('entity'=>$entity, 'form' => $form->createView());
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "it returns form"? How does the code for that part look like?

Comment: Please show your Controller where you submit your form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just added token, and it works now

```
{% if entity.name == 'My entity' %}
    {{ form_row(form.name, { 'attr':{'disabled':'disabled'} }) }}
{% else %}
    {{ form_row(form.name) }}
{% endif %}
{{ form_row(form._token) }}
```

Answer (score 2):

Browsers do not submit disabled form elements.  So your $form->isValid() is failing because it expects and is not getting one.  You can press F12 on your browser and confirm what is actually being submitted.  Hence your controller code just falls through and renders the form again instead of redirecting as it normally would.

Instead of disabled you could perhaps use readonly.  That would make it more difficult (though by no means impossible) for the user to change the value and it would still get posted.

The best approach is to set the disabled attribute when you are defining your form in Symfony.  By doing so, symfony will handle things for you.  No need for extra logic in twig at all.  However, since you want this done based on a value in the entity then you will need to use the form event system to implement this.  I won't try to give details here because I suspect that readonly will work for you but you can find more info at: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html